# How to self-reference yaml hash data in string

Tags: ansible, yaml, ansible-2.x

I have this yaml structure

```
myProgram:
  - year: year
    exepath: My:\File\Path.exe
    product_id: '{My-Product-ID}'
    product_key: 'My-Product-Key'
    version: version
    args: '/passive /norestart /full /p ProductKey= "{{ _________ }}"' # Call product_key in the blank
```

I originally had `myProgram[0].product_key` in the blank, but that returned a recursive error. What do I put in the blank or is this not possible?

Comment: By design, it's not possible to "self_reference" s key in a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking is not possible, however something close can be done using `yaml alias`:

```
---

- name: Sample playbook
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  hosts: localhost

  tasks:

  - set_fact:
      myProgram:
      - year: year
        exepath: My:\File\Path.exe
        product_id: &anchor '{My-Product-ID}'
        product_key: 'My-Product-Key'
        version: version
        #args: '/passive /norestart /full /p ProductKey= "{{ *anchor }}"' #This does not work
        args: *anchor #This works

  - debug: var=myProgram
```

Output of this program is, notice that we have not set `args` equals to `product_id`, rather we are using `alias` to replace the args node. as far as I know we cannot concatenate the string using `alias`, only replacement of entire node is possible.

```
PLAY [Sample playbook] **********************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "myProgram": [
        {
            "args": "{My-Product-ID}", <--------THIS is alias to product_id
            "exepath": "My:\\File\\Path.exe",
            "product_id": "{My-Product-ID}", <--------THIS
            "product_key": "My-Product-Key",
            "version": "version",
            "year": "year"
        }
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```